# Solving an exponential in terms of another variable

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

This is the equation I am trying to solve:

$$
p=\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(2n+1)}
$$

I am trying to work out `n` in terms of `p`. However, this is where I am stuck:

$$
p\times\ln(2n+1)=\ln(n+1)\\
e^{p\times\ln(2n+1)}=e^{\ln(n+1)}\\
(e^{\ln(2n+1)})^p=n+1\\
(2n+1)^p=n+1\\
???
$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here; any suggestions would be welcome.

Update**: I got horribly confused by terminology - $p\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Didn't realise that natural numbers are integers.

Comment: Does $p\in\mathbb{N}$ or $p\in\mathbb{R}^+$ ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien Apologies; all values here are real (this extends from an exponential graph function I was tweaking)

Answer (score 1):

For $n>0$ we have that

$$n+1 < 2n + 1 \leq (2n+1)^p$$

with $ p > 0$. The strict inequalities means that they will never be equal. However $n=0$ is not possible because that makes the original statement undefined (it fails the "vertical line test" since $n=0$ could make $p$ be any value we want). Therefore the given expression has no solutions.

Comment: apologies for the confusion - p and n can be any real number, not natural number.

Comment: OP did not use function notation, nor did he specify that $p$ must be a function. So while you cannot define $n$ as a function of $p$, there are actually infinite solutions to the equation. Also, $p$ cannot be any value because $n,p\in\Bbb{R}$. $p$ cannot be, for example, $2+3i$.

Comment: @MicahWindsor To address your concerns, plugging in $n=0$ to the original expression give us $\frac{0}{0}$, hence not defined. The vertical line test comment refers to how when you partially invert the expression, there appears to be infinite solutions for $n=0$. Secondly, your last comment says that you are the kind of person who likes to be right by bringing up irrelevant details. "Any value" obviously means any value in the original domain, your last comment has zero relevancy other than making yourself correct.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah, my bad. I didn't notice that $p(0)$ was indeterminate. However, the fact that $n,p\in\Bbb{R}$ should not be considered "irrelevant" in light of OP's total confusion about number sets. For that reason, I simply suggested you be more specific. Just trying to contribute.